# Error code 1265 not getting into exception block rather coming out of procedure

Tags: mysql

I have the following sample code but I have seeing  the different behaviors  when comes to varchar and integer columns in handling exceptions.

I am fetching name and salary column value from the table but I have declared 
  variables in the procedure which is less the table column size.

so for integer column I am getting the following error

1264 | ERROR 1264 (22003): Out of range value for column 'v_sal'

it is getting into my exception block which I coded in the procedure

but for varchar column I am getting the following error

ERROR 1265 (01000): Data truncated for column 'v_ename' at row 1

but its not getting into my exception block rather throwing error 
and coming out of procedure

why the behavior so how I have to handle this varchar scenario which should gets into my exception block rather coming out abdruptly.

I am using MySQL 5.7

```
Table structure

 empid  int(4) 
 ename  varchar(10)              
 sal    smallint(6)  




CREATE  PROCEDURE samp_proc(in p_empno int(4),
                            out p_sal smallint,
                            out p_error_code INT,
                            out p_errmsg  VARCHAR(500)
 ) 

BEGIN

declare v_ename varchar(3);

declare v_sal tinyint;

DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION

 begin  
    GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1  @sqlstate = RETURNED_SQLSTATE, 
    @errno = MYSQL_ERRNO, @text = MESSAGE_TEXT;

SET @full_error = CONCAT("ERROR ", @errno, " (", @sqlstate, "): ", @text);

    set p_error_code = @errno;

    set p_errmsg = @full_error ;

  select p_error_code,p_errmsg;

  rollback;
 end;


select ename,sal into v_ename,v_sal from kk_chk where empid = p_empno;

  /* since ename is first in the fetch the varchar behavior takes the precedence
     if we make sal column as first in the fetch the integer behavior takes the precdednce */


end $$

delimiter ;
```

thanks & regards

Karthikeyan.R

Answer (score 0):

I think the error block is behaving as expected.
given

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from users;
+------+------+----------+-------+-----------+----------+---------+
| id   | name | password | email | firstname | lastname | sal     |
+------+------+----------+-------+-----------+----------+---------+
|    1 | aaa  | NULL     | NULL  | aaa       | aaa      | 1000000 |
|    2 | bbbb | NULL     | NULL  | NULL      | NULL     | 1000000 |
+------+------+----------+-------+-----------+----------+---------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

This slightly amended procedure

```
drop procedure if exists samp_proc;
delimiter $$

CREATE  PROCEDURE samp_proc(
    in p_empno int(4)
    #,out p_sal smallint,out p_error_code INT,out p_errmsg  VARCHAR(500)
 ) 
BEGIN
declare v_ename varchar(3);
declare v_sal tinyint;
declare v_id int;
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION

 begin  
    GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1  @sqlstate = RETURNED_SQLSTATE, 
    @errno = MYSQL_ERRNO, @text = MESSAGE_TEXT;

    SET @full_error = CONCAT("ERROR ", @errno, " (", @sqlstate, "): ", @text);
    #set p_error_code = @errno;
    #set p_errmsg = @full_error ;
     #select p_error_code,p_errmsg;
     select 'error block message - ' ,@errno,@full_error;
#  rollback;
 end;

    select name,sal,id into v_ename,v_sal,v_id from users where id = p_empno;

  /* since ename is first in the fetch the varchar behavior takes the precedence
     if we make sal column as first in the fetch the integer behavior takes the precdednce */
end $$

delimiter ;
```

Produces these results

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> call samp_proc(1);
+------------------------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
| error block message -  | @errno | @full_error                                                        |
+------------------------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
| error block message -  |   1264 | ERROR 1264 (22003): Out of range value for column 'v_sal' at row 1 |
+------------------------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> call samp_proc(2);
+------------------------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| error block message -  | @errno | @full_error                                                     |
+------------------------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| error block message -  |   1406 | ERROR 1406 (22001): Data too long for column 'v_ename' at row 2 |
+------------------------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Maybe I have the model wrong but it looks fine to me.

Comment: Thanks  for the reply, with same code only table name changed but still I am getting the same behavior for  name column. 
ERROR 1265 (01000): Data truncated for column 'v_ename' . 
But you are getting error code 1406 but for me 1265 how come codes varies for same scenario any config settings?